# OpenGL textures width and height must be same size?

Tags: opengl

I saw some game using textures such as 256x512, is this standard opengl feature? and is it supported by all drivers?

I've had the impression that *both* width and height must be same size (and power of two). But can they really be different size (but still power of two) ?

**Edit:** also i would like to know that is there any performance differences with 512x128 vs 256x256 (same memory use) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the spec or the [docs](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml):

For power-of-two textures and ignoring borders `width = 2^n` and `height = 2^m`, where `n` and `m` can be different numbers.

`width` or `height` cannot exceed [`GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml).

As far as performance goes you can't really know ahead of time if a given GL implementation uses [linear or tiled](http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/HowVideoCardsWork#VideoRam) texture representations internally.  A tiled implementation won't really care if you have a 1024x16 or 16x1024 texture, since all the caches see are little (for example) 16x16 chunks of texels.  A linear implementation will have a much better cache hit rate on a 16x1024 texture than a 1024x16, assuming row-major storage.

Comment: does modern GFX cards use linear then? (i've read somewhere that mobile phones use tiled chunks because it doesnt need high frequency memory or something like that which would take more battery power)

Comment: @Rookie: Could go either way.  Modern cards are generally fast enough that you probably won't be able to notice the difference on such small textures though :)

Answer (score 0):

no there is no such limit on the size of textures. if there were such limit it would be <strike>impossible</strike> difficult to apply textures to a complex 3d model.

Comment: Why would it be impossible?  Since you can easily use parts of a large texture, constraining the aspect ratio would be no issue at all.

Comment: lets make this clear: so i can really use 256x512 textures and that will work on the oldest hardware too?

Comment: @Rookie: How old are we talking?  Voodoo-class hardware only supported up to 256x256, for instance.

Comment: @genpfault, the size of the texture memory isnt the point here, but the possibility to do for example 256x128 or 64x128 etc

Comment: also i would like to know that is there any performance differences with 512x128 vs 256x256 (same memory use) ?